# Angularjs - javascript date format issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to format my date:

```
var startdate = new Date(someDate).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {  
                    year: 'numeric',
                    month: 'short',
                    day: 'numeric'
                }).split(' ').join('-');
```

and I `console.log` it appear:

> 3-Mar-2016

which is exactly what I want. But what appear in `html` when I `{{someDate}}` or `{{someDate.toString()}}` it become:

> Thu Mar 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (MYT)

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to this link [AngularJs:API:date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)
you can format it like this

```
{{someDate| date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```